# Stuck in a loop using Eclipse/Java

Tags: eclipse, loops

I'm trying to figure out while loops and in the process of testing and running the program, the input window is stuck asking me the same question. I can restart the program but there has to be another way. I've searched the site and there are some similar links but not exact. Please, with simplicity, provide me with some sort of an escape command so this window will close without me restarting Eclipse.

Comment: Are you talking about a program you wrote in Java using Eclipse? If yes, post the relevant source code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be a Terminate button in the Console tab when you run the application through Eclipse.

[image: Terminate]

Clicking that will terminate the running process without exiting Eclipse.